# Is this valid def "${var1}xxx in groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is this valid in Jenkins?

```
def compToBuild = [comp1, comp2, etc]
compToBuild.each{ comp ->
    def "${comp}ToBuild" = [
        "${comp}":   "get${comp}ToBuild()"
        ]
}
def getComp1ToBuild(){
...
}
def getComp2ToBuild(){
...
}
```

Basically, compToBuild will have 1 or more items and iterate through each to get each comp build properties which will be a nested map (getComp1ToBuild)
I could do this:

```
def comp1ToBuild = [
    comp1: getComp1ToBuild()
]
def comp2ToBuild = [
    comp2: getComp2ToBuild()
]
def comp3ToBuild = [
    comp3: getComp3ToBuild()
]
```

but I don't want to do this, if above can't be done, is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why do you need to create dynamic variables? why not to use one map variable with dynamic properties inside?

Comment: how you are going to use those dynamic variables?

Comment: comp will be dynamic inputs, where it can have 1 or more and based on that specific getComp1ToBuild is called to retrieve mapped info for that particular comp; similarly if the input has 2 comp, then each get function to be called and combined together

Comment: @daggett can you provide an example for your "...why not to use one map variable with dynamic properties inside?"

Comment: `def compToBuildMap = compToBuild.collectEntries{ comp-> ["${comp}":"get${comp}ToBuild()" ]}` - this will give you a map `[comp1: getComp1ToBuild, ...]`